# How to get variable out of a nested loop?

Tags: python, loops, variables

My question is very simple how can I get the result variable out of this nested loop:

```
for row in new_matrix:
    for col in row:
        if col == 'S':
            result = [(new_matrix.index(row), row.index(col))]
```

I tried assigning a global variable result above and set it equal to this expression `[(new_matrix.index(row), row.index(col))]` but it didn't work, I want to do it without using `global` because it's bad practice

Comment: return it from a function.

Comment: if you do not want to look further,just use break to finish the loop

Comment: @JurajBezručka can't break a *nested* loop.

Comment: Also your second for loop is not properly indented.

Comment: Assigning a default value to a variable and then changing it inside a a (nested) loop is not what is meant about avoiding global variables — which are variables defined _outside of a function or method_ whose values get changed inside one. Here's more [information](https://proxy.c2.com/cgi/fullSearch?search=GlobalVariablesConsideredHarmful). In other words, your code is basically fine except for assigning an initial value to the variable before entering the loops which in your case that didn't work because `row` and `col` are only defined inside them. The fix is to simply use `None` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Lists are mutable in python, so you can do this way:

```
result = []
for row in new_matrix:
   for col in row:
      if col == 'S':
         result.append(new_matrix.index(row), row.index(col))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def your_function():
    for row in new_matrix:
        for col in row:
            if col == 'S':
                return [(new_matrix.index(row), row.index(col))]

result = your_function()
```